# Problems rescaling a gameObject in script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am attempting to re-scale a game object upon colliding with another object so that the y value is reduced to give a flattening effect. Here is my attempt. Can't figure out why it is not working. The gameObject does not re-scale at all.

```
print ("Entered Collision");
            if (crusherMagnitude > 3.0 && collisionMagnitude > 3.0) {
                print ("CRUSHED");
                Vector3 scale = transform.localScale;
                scale.y = .2F;
                transform.localScale = scale;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post some of the surrounding code?

What I think happens is that you scale the wrong object of the collision.

If your collision  looks like

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{ ....
```

You want to scale the 'other' object. So your code would be:

```
if (crusherMagnitude > 3.0 && collisionMagnitude > 3.0) {
            print ("CRUSHED");
            Vector3 scale = other.transform.localScale;
            scale.y = .2F;
            other.transform.localScale = scale;
        }
```

Comment: I am attempting to scale the object that is attached to the script, so it I think it should just be transform.localScale

Comment: just do: other.tranform.localScale = new Vector3(0,0.2f,0);

Comment: Then the x and z axis will be zero instead of their previous values. So it's not the same thing.